# Dokku .profile.d folder, scripts not executing

Tags: dokku

I cannot get bash scripts to run in the .profile.d folder. This seems like it should be very straight forward but I'm not having any luck.

I have a .profile.d folder in the root of my application. In it I have one script which builds ffmpeg from source called:

ffmpeg.sh

This script executes fine when I run it in the container and makes / installs ffmpeg. I've tried chmod +x and adding a #!/bin/bash to the top of the file.

I feel like I'm missing a basic understanding somewhere here, any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this was running correctly, it just didn't output echo statements. I only found it by attaching to the running docker container after the deploy had finished.